# brew services start mysql vs mysql.server start

Tags: mysql, homebrew

What is the difference between those two below?

```
brew services start mysql

mysql.server start
```

I am using homebrew mac os mysql(5.7.21).

If I turn on the mysql server using a command

```
brew services start mysql
```

then check if that mysql server is on,

```
brew services list
```

The result is

```
mysql started
```

By the way, If I turn on the mysql server using a command

```
mysql.server start
```

then check if that mysql server is on,

```
brew services list
```

The result is

```
mysql stopped
```

Both of them successfully turn on the mysql server.

I have checked it using a command

```
lsof -i:3306
```

But why is that brewlist status different?

I only installed mysql via homebrew.

```
brew install mysql
```

so I guesssed that mysql.server start command also would be related to the homebrew mysql.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`brew services` (services in general) will restart automatically after rebooting; the other (`mysql.server start`) will not. That is the difference. Executing the command with no options should yield,

> ```
> tigger2:Downloads efrisch$ brew services
> brew services [-v|--verbose] [list | run | start | stop | restart | cleanup] [...]
> Easily start and stop formulae via launchctl.
> With -v or --verbose, print more detail.
>
> Integrates Homebrew formulae with macOS' launchctl manager. Services can be
> added to either /Library/LaunchDaemons or ~/Library/LaunchAgents.
> Basically, items in /Library/LaunchDaemons are started at boot, while those
> in ~/Library/LaunchAgents are started at login.
> ```

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding. I cannot fully understand "after rebooting". Is that you are meaning terminal reboot? After brew services mysql stop, rebooting the terminal and check the brewlist status, still mysql stopped

Comment: and also brewlist status show that mysql been stopped, but when I check the lsof -i:3306, mysql still runs.

Comment: Is that "restart" important difference..?

Comment: If you say brew services start and then reboot your mac, then it will start mysql for you. If you manually stop it, of course it is stopped. How often do you reboot? At least after every os update...

Comment: Appreciate it. Better be use brew services start.

Comment: How do you start on linuxhomebrew?