Formula 'mysql' is not installed but mysql --version returns a version
I returned to using mySQL after a long time, and I used the command to check and confirm that I have mySQL installed:
mysql --version
Since it returned a version, I thought my laptop already has mySQL. But when I run the command:
brew services start mysql
it tells me:
Error: Formula 'mysql' is not installed.

I am confused.
Why is this the case? Am I missing something?

It may have been installed some other way than Homebrew, such as with MAMP.

This might be helpful for your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157541/brew-services-start-mysql-vs-mysql-server-start

Run which mysql at a shell prompt. What does it say?

the mysql binary is the client; presumably the services start is the server (though I thought that was services start mysqld).  you can have either or both installed independently
